# It possible to open iOS system crop edit in my app Objective c ?

Tags: objective-c

Now I work with UIImagePickerController and the crop image is a square.

this what I have now:
[image]

and this is what I want! it is possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use CGImageCreateWithImageInRect for Crop Images:

```
CGImageRef RefImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([uncroppedImage CGImage], bounds);
UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:RefImage];
CGImageRelease(RefImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of such "modules"/"libraries" available on GitHub for free. For example, the first match to the search I ran was:
https://github.com/myang-git/iOS-Image-Crop-View

You might find a suitable one.